# How do you share Java functions without giving others source code?

Tags: java, c++

When programming in C++ we have header files and source files. When our company sells our product (which is just a library of useful functions essentially) we provide the client only our header files and compiled source code (not the actual source code). This way clients buying the code see the function definitions in the header files and can make calls to these functions using the compiled code.

How would a company who is developing in Java go about sharing their library functionality without giving out their code? Since there are no header files in Java is this just done through documentation; i.e, provide the client with an API document showing all the function signatures and also provide a jar file with the compiled classes?

Comment: I have no idea, just want to point out that last time I checked, `jar` files could easily be decompiled. I tried once and it even recovered variable names and all.

Comment: If you're tremendously worried about decompilers, use a tool like Proguard to minify and obfuscate your code.

Comment: In Java you don't even try. Since the application is delivered as *byte code* you are always able to *decompile* it. The only way to protect the source is not to shipp the app. So your only option is to provide your app as a Service running on a server you own.

Comment: With C++, there can be a lot of optimization done at compile time. As a result the machine code is hard to translate back into source. But in Java, those optimizations are done at runtime, so they can be tailored specifically to the system a program is running on (i.e. Just-In-Time compilation). A side effect is that the intermediate language (bytecode) is relatively easy to translate back into source, since there is almost no optimization done at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

In Java you don't need source code to compile against - the bytecode contains all the metadata you need.

So for example, if I create an interface with some methods in, compile it into a class file, then package that up into a jar file and give you that jar file, you can use that interface and see all it's members etc without having the source code.

Typically you'd *also* provide documentation to explain the *meaning* of the methods etc, but they're not required in order to compile against the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example [YWorks YFiles](http://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles), they offer their proprietary lib but they do some obfuscation on their distribution(using their own [obfuscator](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard)).

As for guidance how to use their lib, they ship their lib with javadocs, some howto documents and some sample code.